# Custom Forms and UI for related records - f.pauseValidation is not a function

Tags: react-admin

**What you were expecting:**
The custom form show

**What happened instead:**
f.pauseValidation is not a function is throw

**Steps to reproduce:**
Work according to the sample at https://marmelab.com/blog/2018/08/27/react-admin-tutorials-custom-forms-related-records.html

```
React-admin version: 3.2.2
Last version that did not exhibit the issue (if applicable):2.9.6
React version:16.9.0
Browser: Chrome
Stack trace (in case of a JS error):

 above error occurred in the <ReactFinalForm> component:
    in ReactFinalForm (created by FormWithRedirect)
    in FormWithRedirect (created by SimpleForm)
    in SimpleForm (at QuickCreateShippingAddressButton.js:94)
```